# Append in an array results in a list Python

Tags: python, arrays, append

I have the following code

```
points=candies
K=5
centers = []
for i in range(K):
  centers.append(random.choice(points))
centers
```

which results in basically a list of arrays

```
[array([0.6 , 0.92, 0.29]),
 array([0.99, 0.23, 0.45]),
 array([0.65, 0.6 , 0.03]),
 array([0.21, 0.22, 0.55]),
 array([0.62, 0.84, 0.83])]
```

What I want would be a single array like

```
array[[0.6 , 0.92, 0.29],
[0.99, 0.23, 0.45],
[0.65, 0.6 , 0.03],
[0.21, 0.22, 0.55],
[0.62, 0.84, 0.83]]
```

What do I have to change?

Comment: Change `centers` data type to `point`'s data type i.e., numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either convert the list of arrays to a 2D array:

```
np.array(centers)
```

Or start right from an empty array and populate it:

```
centers = np.empty((K,3))
for i in range(K):
  centers[i] = random.choice(points)
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to python, I always thought I don't have to initialize arrays, is that wrong?

Comment: In NumPy, you have to.

Comment: out of curiosity, could you produce the same result with append()? if I do np.array(centers), centers.append() does not work anymore

Comment: @GerardJúlio `numpy.ndarray` objects are different from built-in `list` objects. The former are essentially object-oriented wrappers over primitive, fixed-size arrays, implementing a multidimensional array interface. The latter are heterogenous, sequence-like containers which dynamically resize.

Comment: You confuse arrays and lists. Appending to arrays is expensive and inefficient. When you know the array shape (and you do), declare it ahead of time.